# TCP connection is not giving me output second time

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking

I have made server/client with TCP connection, which converts **bin to dec** or **dec to bin** and returns the output to the client. The program is running fine with one iteration

**Problem**

When I want to get the output(conversion) again without quitting the program, I enter a number and it sends that number to the server, the server doesn't responds back, the cursor starts blinking and shows no output. I waited for like 5 min and nothing happened.

I don't understand why this is happening

PS: pardon my code, I know it can be improved. I just want it to show output again and again

Here's my code. **Assume** all libraries are imported and all conversion functions are running fine and included

**SERVER**

```
print('The server is ready')

message = "yes"
connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

while 1:

    while(message == "yes"):

            print(connectionSocket.getpeername())
            sentence = connectionSocket.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
            number = connectionSocket.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')

            #  binary to decimal conversion
            if(sentence == 'bin_to_dec'):
                    digits = str(binToDec(number))
                    connectionSocket.send(digits.encode('utf-8'))

            # decimal to binary conversion        
            elif(sentence == 'dec_to_bin'):
                    numbers = str(decToBin(number))
                    connectionSocket.send(numbers.encode('utf-8'))

            # If everything fails
            else:
                    print("Wrong input!")
                    connectionSocket.close()

            if(connectionSocket.recv(4096).decode('utf-8') == "no"):
                    break
connectionSocket.close()
```

**Client**

```
clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))

# flag to check if the user wants to end the input
end_everything = False
again = 'yes'


while(end_everything == False):

# while the user wants to input again
while(again.lower() == "yes"):

    # input
    sentence = str(input('bin_to_dec or dec_to_bin >: '))

    # checking whether the input is correct
    if(sentence.lower() == "bin_to_dec" or sentence.lower() == "dec_to_bin"):

        # inputting the number to convert
        number = str(input("which number or digits you want to convert >: "))

        #encodes the input and sends it to the server
        clientSocket.send(sentence.encode('utf-8'))
        clientSocket.send(number.encode('utf-8'))

        #resonse from the server
        modifiedSentence = clientSocket.recv(4096)

        response = modifiedSentence.decode('utf-8')
        #prints that response
        print('From Server: ', response)

        #prompting user, if they want to input again
        message = input("type 'yes' or 'no' if you want to input again: ")
        if(message.lower() == "yes"):
            #clientSocket.send(message.encode())
            continue

        elif(message.lower() == "no"):
            clientSocket.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
            again = 'no'

        else:
            print("Please enter correct input")
    else:
        print("Not valid input!")
        break


clientSocket.close()
```

Comment: TCP does not provide any message boundaries, only a stream of bytes. When you call `socket.recv(4096)` it's possible that the server is receiving *both* the "sentence" and the number in the first receive call, so the second is likely blocking.

Comment: So, what should be the fix?

Comment: As @brent says, you need to have some idea of messages built into the bytes sent between client and server. It's common to prefix each message with a four-byte int, which gives the size of the message. The receiver reads four bytes, converts that to an int, and then reads the number of bytes indicated.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all, yes, your close is a little rough.  It's actually a little difficult to follow, mainly because I'm not as used to python probably.  "while 1" always hurts, but I do it too.

So, my first guess is the "serverSocket.accept()" call on the server.  It looks like you accept a connection, receive data, send, and then loop around and accept a new connection.   Client side expects to keep sendings messages over and over.

You probably want that serverSocket.accept() moved to the outside while loop instead, so it keeps reading from your connection until it closes down.

Comment: Still not fixed

Comment: Good call bnaecker.  You need to receive the same number of bytes that you send.  Otherwise, you're out of sync.  This could be handled different ways, either you always have a set size you send, which you don't as your message could be any given size, or first you send the size of message in an integer type value, then send the message.  On the receive side, you first receive an int, then do a receive on that many bytes.

Comment: But consider it from the user's point of view, he/she will not know what should be the size, any way around this?

Comment: And if that's the case then why it's working for the first time?

Comment: That's why you pass the size yourself.  So the user receives a 4-byte integer for example with the size (let's say 50 bytes).  Then the user receives a 50 byte message.  Now the user sends the same way.  Next time around, you loop and try to receive the 4-byte header again.

Comment: I can't see how I can implement it into my existing code. Please show me how.